# Accessing windows phone 7.5 local data without using zune

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, windows-phone

How can I access the local phone contents on a Windows Phone 7.5 (Samsung Omnia W) without connecting the Zune? Is it possible to tweak the Windows Registry to do the same? Please help me.

Comment: Your can't.  You might be able to find an alternative if you upgrade the phone to 7.8.

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/316/106

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: you can...sort of. You can at least download/upload photo's and video, but music is a bit more difficult; it won't be recognized as an album from an artist.

See the link below:

http://www.wpcentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-phone-7-device-usb-drive